# Taking printscreens of Android Phones?

Tags: android, gps, android-emulator, screenshot

How can I take the printscreen of the android phone?? I am doing an application with GPS. So I cannot use emulator to take the printshot.. Is there any app to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Connect your phone via USB, go to Debug perspective in Eclipse, select the "Devices" tab, select your device in the list and click the "Screen Capture" icon.

Answer (score 2):

The Android emulator provides an [Emulator Console](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#console) that you can use to "dynamically query and control the simulated device environment." In this case, you can use it to set the GPS location.

For example, to set the latitude and longitude, use the following emulator console command (where `<latitude>` and `<longitude>` are your desired values):

```
fix <longitude> <latitude>
```

By using this command, you *can* use the emulator to take a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

If your device is rooted, there's an app called ShootMe that you can use. If not (and if you don't plan on rooting), Donut and Brandon's methods will work, depending on if you'd rather use the device or the emulator. ShootMe will not work without root access.

Answer (score 0):

To take a printscreen from my Samsung Galaxy GIO (Android 2.3.3) I just hold the back button and press the Home button...